# Sync sdcard folder with dropbox api in android application

Tags: android, synchronization, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've researched a lot for How to sync a folder on dropbox using the dropbox api. But i could not find any solution for this. 
I can upload file to dropbox using api but acctually i want whole folder sync with dropbox.

Please help me if there is any solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.
Preet_Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the new Dropbox Sync API [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync)